# How to highlight both multipolygon on map and name in div

Tags: javascript, leaflet, mouseevent, geojson

I am new to JS and I'm seeking for help because I am at dead end. I struggle for a couple of days on events in JS / LeafletJS :(

I want to highlight the element on the map and corresponding data listed in div. I don't know how to select both and do an event on mouseover and mouseout to highlight it

I've stopped on highlight object on map but with no success with div :(

```
    function highlightFeature(e) {
        var layer = e.target;

        layer.setStyle({
            color: '#666' ,
            fillOpacity: 0.7
        })
    }

    function resetHighlight(e) {
        geoJSON.resetStyle(e.target);
    };

    function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
        layer.on({
            mouseover : highlightFeature,
            mouseout: resetHighlight
        });
    };
```

Here's JSFiddle of what I've done so far.

https://jsfiddle.net/JohnDoeJr/jcxz2ruw/6/

I expect that when you put the mouse over multipolygon it will change appearance (highlight) and in div the corresponding data will also highlight and vice versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add an id to each layer and the assign same id to the corresponding text

```
geoJSON.eachLayer(function (layer) {
    layer._path.id = layer.feature.properties.Name;  // This assigns id to each layer with the layer name          
);  
function updateList(target){
    var displayed = target.getLayers();
    var list = document.getElementById('displayed-list');
    list.innerHTML = "";
    displayed.forEach(function(borders){
      var li = document.createElement('li');
      li.innerHTML = borders.feature.properties.Name;
      li.setAttribute("id", borders.feature.properties.Name); // this assigns id to the text with layer's name
      list.appendChild(li);
    });
}
```

And add these style on hover over th geoJSON layer

```
    function highlightFeature(e) {
        var layer = e.target;

        layer.setStyle({
            color: '#666' ,
            fillOpacity: 0.7
        })
        id = e.target.feature.properties.Name
        $("li#"+id).css("font-weight","bold")
    }

    function resetHighlight(e) {
        geoJSON.resetStyle(e.target);
        id = e.target.feature.properties.Name
        $("li#"+id).css("font-weight","")
    };
```

And don't forget to include jQuery.

You can add the same function to text on hover which I have not included.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/JohnDoeJr/jcxz2ruw/13/ i strugle with this second function when mouse hovers text ;/ any help ? explanation ?